# Dictionary from CSV file using the DictReader object

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

To set the context i need to transform a csv file as per my requirements to create a transformed csv output file.

For this problem statement i learned that i need to use a `DictReader` from python csv. After transformation i tried creating another dictionary called new_point which needs to be persisted to a csv file.

The issue is, dictionary generation seems to be flawed in my code as when i print the dictionary it is neither an array of dictionaries nor a dictionary.

```
with open(out_file, 'w') as f_out, open(in_file, 'r') as f_in:
        out_colnames = ['duration', 'month', 'hour', 'day_of_week', 'user_type']        
        trip_writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames = out_colnames)
        trip_writer.writeheader()

        trip_reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)

        # collect data from and process each row
        for row in trip_reader:
            # set up a dictionary to hold the values for the cleaned and trimmed
            # data point
            new_point = {}
            ## TODO: use the helper functions to get the cleaned data from  ##
            ## the original data dictionaries.                              ##
            ## Note that the keys for the new_point dictionary should match ##
            ## the column names set in the DictWriter object above.         ##
            duration = duration_in_mins(row, city)
            month,hour,day_of_week = time_of_trip(row, city)
            user_type = type_of_user(row, city)

            new_point['duration'] = duration
            new_point['month'] = month
            new_point['hour'] = hour
            new_point['day_of_week'] = day_of_week
            new_point['user_type'] = user_type

            pprint(new_point)
```

if i print the `type(new_point)` i am getting the output as below

```
Class <Dict>
```

when i print the new_point dict i am getting the below.

```
{'day_of_week': 'Thursday',
 'duration': 7.123116666666666,
 'hour': 22,
 'month': 3,
 'user_type': 'Registered'}
{'day_of_week': 'Thursday',
 'duration': 9.792516666666668,
 'hour': 22,
 'month': 3,
 'user_type': 'Registered'}
{'day_of_week': 'Thursday',
 'duration': 6.632983333333333,
 'hour': 22,
 'month': 3,
 'user_type': 'Registered'}
{'day_of_week': 'Thursday',
 'duration': 7.4047,
 'hour': 22,
 'month': 3,
 'user_type': 'Registered'}
{'day_of_week': 'Thursday',
 'duration': 13.014583333333333,
 'hour': 22,
 'month': 3,
 'user_type': 'Registered'}
{'day_of_week': 'Thursday',
 'duration': 17.0552,
 'hour': 22,
 'month': 3,
 'user_type': 'Registered'}
{'day_of_week': 'Thursday',
 'duration': 11.01165,
 'hour': 22,
 'month': 3,
 'user_type': 'Registered'}
{'day_of_week': 'Thursday',
 'duration': 30.01175,
 'hour': 21,
 'month': 3,
 'user_type': 'Registered'}
```

Can someone who has already followed this approach of creating a dictionary from a DictReader object help me solving this problem.

If you find this question very naive my sincere apologies. I am completely new to python. I tried reading the docs but did not understand the concept. I could not even find a detailed explanation anywhere.

Comment: "when i print the dictionary it is neither an array of dictionaries nor a dictionary" Can you explain that statement? It *looks* like a dictionary in the output you've shown.

Comment: @larsks I am not sure about that :).It looks like a dictionary but when i iterate using the for loop it is no working as in case of dict.

Comment: Right after the `pprint` line, how about inserting a line that says `trip_writer.writerow(new_point)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I saw, `new_point` looks good: it is a dictionary with the keys which are the same as your column headers. I don't see any statement which writes to the output, however. How about writing your dictionary out after you constructed it?

```
        new_point['duration'] = duration
        new_point['month'] = month
        new_point['hour'] = hour
        new_point['day_of_week'] = day_of_week
        new_point['user_type'] = user_type
        trip_writer.writerow(new_point)  # Write to the file
```